# Oracle DB - Select Multiple Columns As Alias

Tags: oracle, alias

When working with Oracle is it possible to select multiple columns at once and assign them each an alias? I have Googled around but can't seem to come up with a straight answer. An example of what I want to do would be something like:

```
SELECT prod_id, prod_name AS "Product ID", "Product Name" FROM tbl_products
```

When I run this I get the error: ORA-00904: "Product Name": invalid identifier

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean like this:

```
SELECT prod_id AS "Product ID", prod_name AS "Product Name" FROM tbl_products
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - I feel like such an idiot with the solution being so simple!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help:P. Remember to accept the answer if you are fine with it.